# Crear Select en cascada

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo dos controles select que los he creado asi:

```
 @Html.Action("BuscarArticuloLinea", "ArticuloLinea", New With {.IdArticuloLinea = 0})
 @Html.Action("BuscarArticuloSubLinea", "ArticuloSubLinea", New With {.IdArticuloSubLinea = 0, .IdArticuloLinea = 0})
```

En el caso del primero

> "BuscarArticuloLinea"

llama a un controlador que invoca a una vista parcial en la cual creo el select...el controlador se encarga de llenar dicho select". En el caso del segundo select este tiene que llenarse a la hora de elegir un item del primer select...es eso lo que no logro hacer. Al cargar la pagina los dos combos se crean y solo se llena el primero como debe de ser. ¿Cual es la forma de llenar el segundo select al seleccionar un item del primero?...espero sus respuestas...gracias

Answer (score 1):

Este metodo esta en el Controlador

```
public JsonResult BuscarArticulos(string id)
    {
        var query= db.Articulos.Where(m => m.IdPadre.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(id))).ToList();
        return Json(new SelectList(query, "Id", "Nombre"));
    }
```

Vista

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#BuscarArticuloLinea").change(function () {
        $("#BuscarArticuloSubLinea").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("BuscarArticulos")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: $("#BuscarArticuloLinea").val() },
            success: function (articulos) {
                $.each(articulos, function (i, data) {
                    $("#BuscarArticuloSubLinea").append('<option value="' + data.Value + '">' + data.Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Error.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BuscarArticuloLinea, ViewBag.BuscarArticuloLinea as SelectList, "Seleccione Articulo en Linea", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("BuscarArticuloSubLinea", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Seleccione Articulo en SubLinea", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```